# TypeScript: Check if variable has been initialised

Tags: typescript

I have some function as follows:

```js
const myFunction = (columns: any, data: any) => {
  let label: string;
  let value: number;

  //some section where it assigns label and value
  for (let index = 0; index < columns.length; index++) {
        const column: string = columns[index].fieldName;
        const datapoint: string = data[index].formattedValue;

        if (column.includes("KeyPointLabel")) {
            label = datapoint;
        }
        if (column.includes("KeyPointValue")) {
            value = Number(datapoint);
        }
    }

  //if the above section worked as expected, they should have a value.
  //so if it doesn't, throw an error.
  if (typeof label === undefined) throw new Error() <--- ERROR HERE!!

  return {label, value}
}
```

I want to null check for `label` and `value`. I have looked at a couple of other threads where it suggested to do `if (typeof label === undefined)` or `if (label == null)`, etc. but any statement that references `label` or `value` gives me 'used before assigned' error.

The section where it assigns `label` and `value` is just a for-loop which looks through the `columns` to see if it has a column name that contains `KeyPointLabel`, assigns `label = data[same index as column]`, and similarly for `value`. The form of `columns` and `data` is not something I can control.

Technically, I could do

```js
  let label: string = "";
  let value: number = -1;

  ...

  if(label === "" || value < 0) throw new Error();

  return { label, value }
```

because my `value` is never expected to have a negative number and `label` never to be an empty string, but I was wondering if there is a bit more elegant solution.

Comment: What is `//some section where it assigns label and value`? Sounds like it'd make the most sense by far to throw in there when the conditional assignment fails, instead of afterwards

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited my question to add more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the `used before assigned` error is because Typescript doesn't know that `undefined` is a possible value/type for `label` or even the other `value`.

Your first codeblock actually works if you just simply specify the type as:

```
  let label: string | undefined;
  let value: number | undefined;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 2):

I would just declare it as possibly being `undefined`, because it is:

```
  let label: string | undefined;
  let value: number | undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the '!' ([Definite Assignment Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)).

Example:

```
let label!: string;
let value!: number;
```

Example: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIFczCgS3DAvDAClABsU5IAuGAQzAQBoYATaqaq2hASjwD4YA3gCgYMYgFNYxagCNxxAIRVoAJ0xgA5gG4RYyTABu1UuKUwwZOSp26A9LYgg44mBHEZsYGAHcAFuJUXTFhqCAhMDUgxWXkaMCZDYxRxXQAzEBVCCVh1JnEADzwYAAYtGFyCmAAeGBIySAA6CU0oXzKK-IBqTp5hUX7%200EhYOvJlKDVNItHIAG0OgF0G1Mx5JgA5amcdAYGh6GZWagAHEHUoccmNIpY2efiCpfSVOFYocSYANSTxG13%20zCpQgzBrqYCkPIQAgAIgA0uIEAAFM5gKAAGRixGhXF6un%20A2kcmINyOp3OO3xAF88btAcCQKRyKD0BDxFC4QjkedviZsbj8bsjCYiutLAECLcTiioFwKf9qQNqXZbHTWi5ZCADC43B4cN4MgBrD40CAwArHdzvJiMNUIVy%20EAoYgJXzULU0RImBrKxzlIHBZggNlgADkUBtvhUIG8cTNKijKm9ojpBEJsVwGZgaDyKzAHx4rSjMbzMYAovGMgRZUJdIEoCgVF4BGniIwhclqZSgA)